# Rename and trim multiple files at once using unix command

Tags: unix

I have some  files having pattern as  name

```
xyz_00011111_03202023_en-GB.pdf
```

I want to rename and trim it to

```
abc_00011111
```

all `xyz` to `abc` and want to remove date and country code in the name for all files in same directory

i was trying something like this

```
$ for f in *.pdf; do mv "$f" $(echo $f | tr 'xyz' 'abc'); done
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ rename -n 's/^xyz/abc/; s/\d{8}_[a-z]{2}-[A-Z]{2}\.pdf//' ./xyz_*.pdf 
rename(xyz_00011111_03202023_en-GB.pdf, abc_00011111)
```

Remove `-n` switch, aka *dry-run* when your attempts are satisfactory **to rename for real**.